# Collation conflict when comparing sql_variant with varchar literal

Tags: sql-server, collation, sql-variant-property

I found that queries below return different results on two Azure Hyperscale databases that are running the same compatibility level, same set options etc.

```sql
IF CAST(ServerProperty('Edition') AS nvarchar(128)) = 'SQL Azure' BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
IF ServerProperty('Edition') = 'SQL Azure' BEGIN
    SELECT 2
END
IF 'SQL Azure' = ServerProperty('Edition') BEGIN
    SELECT 3
END
```

On one database, it returns only 1, on other database it returns 1,2 and 3.

I investigated the root cause and it seems to be caused by different collations of the databases.

For following queries:

```sql
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ServerProperty('Edition'), 'Collation')
SELECT name, collation_name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

The database which returns only one row, the result is:

```
-----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

name         collation_name                   compatibility_level
------------ -------------------------------- -------------------
master       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS     140
my_database  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS   150
```

And the result from database that returns 1,2,3 is:

```
-----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

name         collation_name                   compatibility_level
------------ -------------------------------- -------------------
master       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS     140
my_database  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS     150
```

So the simple comparison without the cast is comparing `sql_variant` with `varchar` (there is no difference when I use `N'SQL Azure'`) where the underlying `nvarchar` from the `sql_variant` has in one case different collation than the DB I query and in other case it's matching.

First of all, I would assume the comparison of two strings with different collation would fail like it fails when you try to join on two columns with different collation, but it's apparently not the case here.

Anyway, what's the best way to safely compare output of a function that might be `sql_variant` with a `varchar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sql_variant` type is at the top of the data precedence hierarchy, so the string literal is implicitly converted to `sql_variant` before the comparison takes place.

The [rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql#comparing-sql_variant-values) for `sql_variant` comparison include (emphasis added):

> - When sql_variant values of different base data types are compared and the base data types are in different data type families, the value whose data type family is higher in the hierarchy chart is considered the greater of the two values.
> - When sql_variant values of different base data types are compared and the base data types are in the same data type family, the value whose base data type is lower in the hierarchy chart is implicitly converted to the other data type and the comparison is then made.
> - When sql_variant values of the char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data types are compared, their **collations are first compared** based on the following criteria: LCID, LCID version, comparison flags, and sort ID. Each of these criteria are compared as integer values, and in the order listed. **If all of these criteria are equal**, then the actual string values are compared according to the collation.

That explains the results you saw.

In [addition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql#converting-sql_variant-data):

> When handling the sql_variant data type, SQL Server supports implicit conversions of objects with other data types to the sql_variant type. However, SQL Server does not support implicit conversions from sql_variant data to an object with another data type.

The rules for [collation precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql) are separate. They apply when comparing strings with different collation labels. See the linked documentation for the gritty details of the *Coercible-default*, *Implicit X*, *Explicit X*, and *No-collation* labels.

Convert the `sql_variant` return value to the base type with the collation of the current database. This will match the collation assigned to the literal value, which should have the N prefix to be interpreted as Unicode.

For my instance, that means:

```
IF CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = 
    N'Developer Edition (64-bit)'
```

The `COLLATE` clause isn't strictly necessary if you provide the string literal exactly as expected, but you did ask for the 'best' way, which I took to mean 'most comprehensive'.

My Czech mate Tomáš Zíka wrote about this and related issues in [Expecting Subvertations](https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/expecting-subvertations/).

Answer (score 5):

> what's the best way to safely compare output of a function that might
> be sql_variant with a varchar?

For `SERVERPROPERTY` that returns `nvarchar`, I suggest the work-around you already discovered plus an `nvarchar` constant instead of `varchar`.

The explicit cast 1) will return an `nvarchar` of the current database collation and 2) avoid the implicit conversion of the varchar constant to sql_variant. The `nvarchar` constant will also be the current database collation and match the explicit cast type, allowing more reliable equality comparison.

```
IF CAST(ServerProperty('Edition') AS nvarchar(128)) = N'SQL Azure'
```